# Facebook Graph API permission issue

Tags: node.js, express, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with querying the Facebook Graph API and reading with extended permissions. I want to query a page's latest posts with additional data for a reporting dashboard (show the number of likes, reactions and post impressions) I have an express app with passport-facebook running in order for the user to authenticate and provide the permissions in question. This setup used to work before, but now I am experiencing a strange problem.

This is what I am requesting: `created_time,link,full_picture,message_tags,with_tags{link},message,reactions.summary(true),insights.metric(post_impressions)`

I had my app in Facebook's review process and they granted me the `read_insights` permission for querying `insights.metric(post_impressions)`. After the review I was able to pull all the data I needed from the API. That was 2 weeks ago. Today I experienced the problem that I can only pull very limited data out of the API. The response keeps giving me `Permission error (OAuthException)`, stating "User doesn't have enough permissions to load insights", "You do not have enough permission to view the metric."

However, when I add the `limit` and/or the `after` params to the query I do get data back, but only with very low values for `limit` (that is <= 5, but after 2 paginated requests, no subsequent requests are allowed) or a value for `after`, which I don't have for an inital request.

Has there been a change to the API (couldn't find anything in the changelog)? Maybe I'm just overlooking something trivial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody else (not here or anywhere else I asked for help) seemed to have experienced the issue I filed a bug at Facebook and it turned out to be an individual problem with some item(s) on my page's feed. Here's their response:

> This is a particular issue with one or more specific posts from that page feed, that is causing the entire call to fail when trying to include it.

This issue might be addressed in a future version of Graph API. There are two workarounds for now: either use a [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens/#page-access-tokens) or if sticking with a user access token, giving it [granular permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/overview/#granularpermissions) to the pages.

I've tried option 1 and a page access token seems to fix the issue.